# Why isn't libgnustl_shared.so being copied from my APK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an android project with a `libs` folder structure like this:

```
/libs
  /armeabi
    libfoo.so
    libbar.so
    libmystuff.so
    libgnustl_shared.so
  /armeabi-v7a
    libfoo.so
    libbar.so
```

`foo` and `bar` are third party libraries, `mystuff` is my own library from a separate android JNI project which requires `gnustl_shared`, which is from the same JNI project.

When I build my project in Eclipse, I can view the contents of the generated APK using `unzip -l`, and it indeed shows that all of these library files have been included.

However, after installing the APK, the `/data/data/com.myproject/lib` folder contains no `libgnustl_shared.so`, even though the other libraries are present.

This inevitably leads to the following error:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gnustl_shared: findLibrary returned null
```

As a sanity check, I ran `adb push ./libs/armeabi/libgnustl_shared.so /data/data/com.myproject/lib` and sure enough, the application starts as expected.

I don't see anything in the build log or Eclipse console that suggests there were any issues building or installing the app.

- What could be preventing `libgnustl_shared.so` from being installed with my application?
- Where can I go to learn about what happens when an APK is installed?

---

Please let me know in a comment if there's any specific information I can provide that might help.

Comment: double check the mainfest for statements including all the libs.

Comment: @RobertRowntree -- Could you explain what you mean? I've never needed to specify libraries in `AndroidManifest.xml` for other projects, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: read here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Comment: This is for referencing other Android library projects that you have source access to. What I have is a combination of some `.jar` files, and some `.so` files. My `project.properties` file makes no references to other library projects, yet `libfoo`, `libbar`, and `libmystuff` are all installed correctly. The only missing library is `libgnustl_shared`. NDK development is anything but smooth. :[

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687287/adding-prebuilt-apk-with-shared-libraries-to-aosp  follow the link under the accepted answer for an explain on what happens during apk 'unpack' on the device and why shared libs may have to be copy manual

Comment: It is packed to apk file but is not being unpacked to `/lib` on installation. That seems to be an issue on android side. Try removing the underscore '_' from the name.

Comment: `libgnustl_shared.so` is a standard library that _ships_ with the android NDK -- Also, why would underscores magically break the findLibrary command?

Comment: @RobertRowntree - that link would only be relevant for APK's packaged **as part of the android system itself** and not for ordinary 3rd party APK's.

Answer (score 2):

I think that, in your JNI project's Android.mk file, most probably, when you build libmystuff.so, you're referencing libgnustl_shared.so like:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lgnustl_shared
```

Maybe you can try to add it as a module (NDK works really focused on modules), something like:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := gnustl_shared 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libgnustl_shared.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and (in the section you're building libmystuff.so):

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gnustl_shared
```

And check if it's finally copied

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gnustl_shared` line.

Answer (score 0):

I think your **libgnustl_shared.so** need under */armeabi-v7a* not under */armeabi*

Please try copy **libgnustl_shared.so** to */armeabi-v7a*

Comment: Hi @namuol ;if your couldn't find *libgnustl_shared.so* under `/data/data/com.myproject/lib` means this lib not be packed to your APK.

Comment: @namuol are your appoint `APP_ABI` in `Application.mk`?by default ,the`APP_ABI` equals **armeabi**,

Comment: No -- `libgnustl_shared.so` is actually in the apk. I have made certain of this.

Comment: @namuol,I think It's better to list your `.MK` files

Comment: What would happen if you deleted the libs/armeabi-v7a directory and left just the armeabi dir in your source?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the answer here: [How to link any library in ndk application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106965/how-to-link-any-libarary-in-ndk-application)
The problem is most likely in your Android.mk file. You should have a line like the one on the bottom:

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

If not, then you're not including your shared library.

Comment: I'm using this exact line in the JNI project where I got `libmystuff.so` and `libgnu_stl_shared.so`; the project I'm referring to in my question is not a JNI project, so no `Android.mk` file is necessary.