# DalvikVM Error: Could not find class 'com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView$3', referenced from method X

Tags: android, air, apk, android-install-apk

I have installed Adobe AIR 3.8 APK on Android 2.3.7 device and following are the major error logs, when an AIR application was opened:

> E/dalvikvm( 4372): Could not find class 'com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView$3', referenced from method com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.DoSetOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener

Adobe AIR installation was successful and its flash screen came up when i pressed Adobe AIR menu icon. Looks like a linkage issue. I have tried several Stackoverflow links on similar issues, but gained nothing.

I tried to install the APK by adding a make file for to the android source build as said in below link but installation didn't happen.
[Error adding prebuilt apk with shared libraries to AOSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687287/adding-prebuilt-apk-with-shared-libraries-to-aosp)

Please help with your suggestions to get it installed, the prebuilt APK without linkage issue.

Comment: Same problem here. Running Air SDK 3.9 and getting the same error.