# AOSP building application with jni libs

Tags: android, android-source, ninja

I am trying to build an Android application inside of AOSP.

I have defined the `Android.bp` file as follows

```
cc_prebuilt_library_shared {
    name: "libPrintString",
    target: {
        android_arm: {
            srcs: ["lib/libPrintString.so"],
        },
        android_arm64: {
            srcs: ["lib64/libPrintString.so"],
        },
    },
    strip: { none:true, },
}

java_import {
    name: "stringutils",
    jars: ["libs/stringutils.jar"],
}

android_app {
    name: "HelloWorld",
    srcs: ["src/**/*.java",],
    platform_apis: true,
    product_specific: true,
    certificate: "platform",
    privileged: true,
    static_libs: [
        "com.google.android.material_material",
        "androidx-constraintlayout_constraintlayout",
        "stringutils",
    ],
    jni_libs: ["libPrintString"]
}
```

I have put my application in the `/packages/apps` folder, the project has the following structure

```
+ HelloWorld
  - Android.bp
  - AndroidManifest.xml
  + lib
    - libPrintString.so
  + lib64
    - libPrintString.so
  + libs
    - stringutils.jar
  + res
  + src
```

When I am calling make I am getting an error

```
FAILED: ninja: 'out/target/product/mydroid/product/lib64/libPrintString.so', needed by 'out/target/product/mydroid/product.img', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Can someone please help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long fights with the build system, I finally found a solution and wrote a small article to describe in details how to build an application with system privileges

[How to Build an Android Application with System Privilegies](https://vapoyan.medium.com/aosp-creating-a-system-application-c9c06249b8cf)

I still did not fully understand why it was not working in the beginning, most probably because somehow my build system was not cleaning old libraries, but now everything is working correctly.

Comment: In mention article I didn't see ```Android.bp``` which is used in question. So it seems that you use another approach  (```Android.mk``` build) to resolve the given issue and it means that issue with using ```Android.bp``` for such purposes is left, am I right?

Comment: Ah, yes you are right, I have not tried with the .bp file, I will do that and see if it is possible, @NikolayKhilyuk Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @ViktorApoyan your article seems to have some broken images (which are quite important)

Answer (score 2):

Your app `HelloWorld` definition has this property `product_specific: true`  which means the app will go to `/product` partition and will search for the libraries in `/product/lib*/`.
But your library `libPrintString` definition don't have `product_specific: true` which means the library goes to `system/lib*/`.

So error makes sense.

To solve your problem, You have to add this property `product_specific: true` to your library definition.

```
cc_prebuilt_library_shared {
    name: "libPrintString",
    target: {
        android_arm: {
            srcs: ["lib/libPrintString.so"],
        },
        android_arm64: {
            srcs: ["lib64/libPrintString.so"],
        },
    },
    strip: { none:true, },
    product_specific: true
}
```

Comment: I followed this but the `.so` file is not a part of the apk. I had to do a full build to get the file in the `/system` directory of my target.