# Android.mk try access .so file

Tags: android

I want to include *.so in Android.mk. Here is my code save in app/jni/Android.mk
The .so file is same in app/jni/libdpfr6.so

My code is 
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libdpfr6
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libdpfr6.so
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

but after running the app I got a error.

LOCAL_SRC_FILES should point to a file ending with ".a"

Android NDK: The following file is unsupported: libdpfr6.so

I need help.

Comment: Do you know the difference between static and dynamic linking? Which one do you want to use?

Comment: you could refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40712837/how-to-add-some-third-party-so-files-in-android-mk